# QRunnable in multiple cores

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am learning about QRunnable and I have the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool, QRunnable

class SomeObjectToDoComplicatedStuff(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, name):
        QRunnable.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        print('running', self.name)
        a = 10
        b = 30
        c = 0
        for i in range(5000000):
            c += a**b
        print('done', self.name)


pool = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
pool.setMaxThreadCount(10)

batch_size = 100

workers = [None] * batch_size

for i in range(batch_size):
    worker = SomeObjectToDoComplicatedStuff('object ' + str(i))
    workers[i] = worker
    pool.start(worker)

print('All cued')
pool.waitForDone()

# processing the results back
for i in range(batch_size):
    print(workers[i].name, ' - examining again.')
```

I see that indeed there are different processes being alternated, but *all is happening on a single core.*

**How can I make this code run using all the processor cores?**

PS: This code is just a simplification of a super complicated number crunching application I am making. In it, I want to to do Monte Carlo in several threads and the worker itself is a complex optimization problem.
I have tried the python multiprocessing module but it doesn't handle scipy too well.

Comment: [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: I am fully aware of the GIL, however the question is still how to make this run in multiple cores.

Comment: That seems like a contradition in terms. If the relevant code doesn't release the GIL, it wil be impossible to make the code in your question behave any differently. The multiprocessing module exists precisely because of this issue. So if you can't use that, you'll have to write an extension that can run the code without the GIL. See: [Overcoming Python's GIL with Cython](http://lbolla.info/blog/2013/12/23/python-threads-cython-gil).

Comment: If you can provide a solution that uses scipy and the multiprocessing module, I'll mark it as the solution

Comment: I thought you'd tried multiprocessing? What specific problems did you have with it? It would be very helpful if you posted a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Multiprocessing launches a function with different sets of inputs, I tried that once indeed. This is to execute a function of different objects in parallel. If I could stack in a pool a list of objects and execute the function run of each of them, to later gather the result that would be ideal.  However the multiprocessing library seems not designed to do that. Hence this question. But if you can do it with the multiprocessing library, be my guest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how much use this will be, but a [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) version of your example script would be something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        print('running', self.name)
        a = 10
        b = 30
        c = 0
        for i in range(5000000):
            c += a**b
        print('done', self.name)
        return self.name, c

def caller(worker):
    return worker.run()

def run():
    pool = Pool()
    batch_size = 10
    workers = (Worker('object%d' % i) for i in range(batch_size))
    result = pool.map(caller, workers)
    for item in result:
        print('%s = %s' % item)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    run()
```

Comment: Looks like this is the way, although on windows it crashes..I'll try on linux later

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera. I fixed the example code. Windows doesn't have *fork*, so the script's entry point must be guarded to avoid an infinite regress.

Comment: Tried on linux with the production code and it worked

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make this code run using all the processor cores?

Using PyQt (QRunner/QThread and likely), I think it's almost impossible because they (the python version, not the C++) are using the GIL.

The easiest solution would be to use `multiprocessing`, but since you have some problem using it along scipy you should look for some non-standard library.

I suggest you to take a look at [ipyparallel](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html), AFAIK they're developed under the same umbrella, so they're likely to work seamlessy.