# Terminating a QThread that wraps a function (i.e. can't poll a "wants_to_end" flag)

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyqt, thread-safety, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a thread for a GUI that wraps a long-running function. My problem is thus phrased in terms of PyQt and QThreads, but I imagine the same concept could apply to standard python threads too, and would appreciate any suggestions generally.

Typically, to allow a thread to be exited while running, I understand that including a "wants_to_end" flag that is periodically checked within the thread is a good practice - e.g.:

```
Pseudocode (in my thread):
def run(self):
    i = 0
    while (not self.wants_to_end) and (i < 100):
        function_step(i)  # where this is some long-running function that includes many streps
        i += 1
```

However, as my GUI is to wrap a pre-written long-running function, I cannot simply insert such a "wants_to_end" flag poll into the long running code.

Is there another way to forcibly terminate my worker thread from my main GUI (i.e. enabling me to include a button in the GUI to stop the processing)?

My simple example case is:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.kwargs = kwargs


    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        result = SomeLongComplicatedProcess(**self.kwargs)
        self.finished.emit(result)
```

with usage within my MainWindow GUI:

```
    self.thread = QThread()
    self.worker = Worker(arg_a=1, arg_b=2)
    self.worker.finished.connect(self.doSomethingInGUI)
    self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
    self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
    self.thread.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the long-running function blocks, the only way to forcibly stop the thread is via its [terminate()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate) method (it may also be necessary to call `wait()` as well). However, there is no guarantee that this will always work, and the docs also state the following:

> **Warning**: This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The
>   thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be
>   terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to
>   clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use
>   this function only if absolutely necessary.

A much cleaner solution is to use a separate *process*, rather than a separate thread. In python, this could mean using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module. But if you aren't familiar with that, it might be simpler to run the function as a script via [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) (which provides signals that should allow easier integration with your GUI). You can then simply [kill()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#kill) the worker process whenever necessary. However, if that solution is somehow unsatisfactory, there are many other [IPC approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Approaches) that might better suit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I tried .terminate() but the thread just kept running! It sounds like multiprocessing is a good route forwards. I'll study the docs now, but if you have a minimum working example at all, that would be great too! Thanks.

Comment: @PhysLQ. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093862/984421) for a simple example.

Comment: Thanks. Is it better to use multiprocessing or a QThread here do you think? I have limited familiarity with either, but will look into them both.

Comment: @PhysLQ. Most people would advise against using `QThread.terminate()` (even if it worked).

Comment: Thanks. I actually meant to ask about the relative merits of QProcess (not QThread) and multiprocessing but that's useful to know too.

Comment: @PhysLQ. The only meaningful way to answer that is to try them with your particular use-case.